# Way to grab a line based on lines value

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have an example like so:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 2.2
1 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 33 1.1
```

11 values per line, all single spaced.

The occasional random character thrown in, but that's it. I'm trying to find a way to copy the line in which the last value is less than a some user/predetermined value. Something akin to a 'grep if $last <= 2', but I can't think of one nor can I find one.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried using REGEX ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple `awk` use case:

```
awk -v val=2 '$NF < val' file
```

**Output:**

```
1 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 33 1.1
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks. Could you explain the $NF part? Also, is that < equivalent to less-than-or-equal to, or just less than? If it is just less than, is there anyway to make it <= ?

Comment: `NF` represents number of field and `$NF` means last field in a row. To make less than equal to use: `awk -v val=2 '$NF <= val' file`